# Issue with emojis rendering in PyCharm output

Tags: pycharm, ide, output, rendering, emoji

I'm trying to create a small program that scraps few films out of the IMDB web-site, and the issue is

- while I'm using PyCharm IDE for this project, I have a weird things going on while using emojis in my output, it's overlapping with the text.

Is there any way to fix it?

Output:
[image: Output]

```py
def get_films(user_mood: str) -> str:
    """
    Generating 5 films for the user.
    :param: user current mood.
    :type: str
    :return: 5 films with description for each one.
    :rtype: str
    """
    # Using 'imdbfilmscrap.py' module to get films.
    films = films_scrap(user_mood)

    # Returns 5 scrapped films.
    print(f"\nHere are five films to watch while you feeling {user_mood.lower()}:\n")
    for film in films:
        print(
            f'️Title: {film["Title"]}\n'
            f'⭐IMDB Rating: {film["IMDB Rating"]}\n'
            f'⌛Length: {film["Length"]}\n'
            f'Genre: {film["Genre"]}\n'
            f'By: {film["By"]}\n'
        )
```

Tried to reinstall PyCharm IDE, also used VS Code as a different IDE for this project and the problem remains the same.